# Is it possible for moderators to delete a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that some questions have the `wordpress.com` tag, which is off-topic here, following by [this](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/tag-for-off-topic-subject-wordpress-com) question.

Now i was wondering, can moderators delete a tag? If `wordpress.com` tag is off-topic here, then why the tag still exists?

Since creating a tag requires a specific reputation, and users asking the questions with `wordpress.com` are mostly new users, then is there a chance this approach will solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag exists for two reasons:

1. Some wordpress.com questions *are* on-topic. Migration from there to a self-hosted installation is a common example.
2. Some users have put that tag on their *ignore* list, and we don't want to break that.

This is similar to other popular off-topic tags, like `woocommerce`.

Moderators cannot delete a tag, but they can merge it into another one. I use `customization` as merge target in most cases, because that tag is completely meaningless otherwise. :)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know woocommerce is off-topic too. But if it's deleted, then how can it break the ignore list? It doesn't exist anymore to appear anywhere.

Comment: People will still ask questions about that topic. That's inevitable.

Comment: @JackJohansson All plugins are technically off-topic until they are eventually merged into core.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Yea, well woocommerce is unofficially part a core though :) I always forget that it's just a plugin.